# Display all usernames saved in database

Tags: php

So I was wondering how do I display all usernames currently saved in my DB?

What I currently have still only displays 1 username

thanks for any help.

```
<?php

 $con = new mysqli("blank", "blank", "blank", "blank");


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id > '0'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);



echo $row['username'];
?>
```

Comment: Well, what data do you have in your DB? Are there any users with an ID greater than 0?

Comment: I did it like this because all my user_ids are above 0

Comment: Its not a duplicate, I just asked this

Comment: @ben Yes all of my IDs are greater then 0

Comment: You have to loop over your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$con = new mysqli("blank", "blank", "blank", "blank");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id > 0");
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $result ) ) {
    echo $row [ 'username' ] ."<br />";
}
```

It's nothing more than looping over your result.

Comment: No problem, anytime :)

Comment: Do you know how I could make them each clickable links as there echo out.

Comment: You just have to change the echo. Make it like: echo "<a href='link here'>". $row [ 'username' ] ."</a><br />";

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php

     $con = new mysqli("blank", "blank", "blank", "blank");


    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id > '0'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    foreach($row as $rs){
echo $rs['name']
}
    }


    ?>
```

Try this

Comment: Still only shows 1 result

Comment: You're doing double work, $row = mysqli_fetch_array and in your while().